# Event data streaming applications with apache kafka in local env and move it to AWS Kafka for pre-prod / prod

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-msk

Is it possible to develop event data streaming applications with apache kafka locally in my laptop using kafka docker and then deploy the application to AWS msk (kafka) so that cost can be saved by using only for pre-prod and production.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is

However, there wouldn't be all that much cost savings because you're effectively paying more for ingress traffic rather than keeping connections within a VPC

The drawback is that it's also not secure and you'll have to port forward your local network's router so that anyone can access your Kafka broker from over the internet, therefore increasing latency as you'd be polling from an upload speed limited by your ISP